# cannot add edges or nodes using networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

i am using python library networkx to create direct graph

```
graph = nx.DiGraph
graph.add_edges_from(edges)
graph.add_nodes_from(isolated_nodes)
```

nothing went wrong until yesterday, add i got error below:

> TypeError: add_edges_from() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ebunch'

But, i acturally passed a tuple list as container of edges, and another list of int as container of nodes.

I print edges tuple list and nodes list I passed into methods and the error that shown as below:

[image]

so to simplify the problem, i test to add one edge or one node like below:

```
graph.add_edge(1,2)
graph.add_node(3)
```

and I still got

> TypeError: add_edge() missing 1 required positional argument: 'v', or add_node() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'

it's weried I can't figure out what's going wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You never created a graph because you never called the constructor. Must be:

```
graph = nx.DiGraph() # Note the ()!
```

Comment: thank u, I waste couple hours on such a stupid mistake